# How to check if a form is modal before it's drawn?

Tags: forms, delphi

Some of my forms can be shown both as normal and modal forms.
In case they're showing as modal forms, I have to hide some components which are not usefull in modal state.

```
if(fsModal in Self.FormState) then
begin 
  //hiding some components...
end;
```

I would like to execute my code before the form is drawn, in order to avoid it's drawn more times unnecessarily.

Comment: What's wrong with the code in the question? Haven't you already found the answer? Personally though this feels wrong. I'd add a bespoke method to the form to show it. Pass as an argument to that method whether to show modally or modeless. Take appropriate actions in that method before calling `Show` or `ShowModal`.

Comment: Where is this executed? In the OnShow event? Because that is where you need it, I think.

Comment: You're the one showing the form. So before you show the form do anything you need to do . Then do `ShowModal`.

Comment: @moskito-x equally, and better, you could override ShowModal, but I don't think that is necessary

Comment: @Dsm : it is so easy and there are many possibilities to customize a form before `ShowModal`

Comment: Currently my code is in the OnShow, I was thinking about something like an "OnBeforeShow", just for comfort reasons. Thanks to all

Comment: You have code that works then. Why are you seeking to change it?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Because I thought that OnShow is triggered after showing form. So I thought that my form would have been drawn one more than necessary. Isn't so?

Comment: What is the downside of having your code in the `OnShow` handler? In any case, I'd do it the way I described above. You don't need to put everything into events. You are permitted to add methods to your classes.  And a form is just a class.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I never said that I disagree with the approach you're suggesting. The downside of using OnShow is the one I wrote in the previous comment, providing that what I wrote is true.

Comment: Is that downside discernible? Does it affect performance in any way?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: In past I have had graphic troubles caused by code in the OnShow. Above all.. why should I draw my form twice if I can do it once? It's an unacceptable thing from my point of view.

Comment: So hide the controls before you `Show` the form then, if you feel strongly about it. Back to my first comment. But I don't think it will make any discernible difference. Can you even see the controls before they are hidden? If so then for sure that would look messy. But so far as I can tell you won't be able to see them. That the form is visible is neither here nor there. Has it actually been painted yet? I doubt it. In other words I think you are concerned about something that does not happen.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I thought that OnShow executed before the form is visible, but it seems that is not so. So you can do this:

```
TMyForm = class( TForm )  // this will already be in your source
public
  function ShowModal: Integer; override;
end;

function TMyForm.ShowModal: Integer;
begin
  // hide some components
  Result := inherited;
  // show them again in case next time it is a Show
end;
```

You can't override Show in the same way - you would have to override the visible property, so easier to reset the visibility of the components as shown.

Answer (score 3):

You can write some initial procedure for two type of showing:

```
(in Form)
procedure TfrmForm01.Init(p_Modal: Boolean);
begin
  if p_Modal then
    begin
      edtForModalForm.Visible := False;  // hide some components
      ShowModal;
    end
  else
    Show;
end;
```

and you can call form by parameter. True for Modal, False for NoModal form:

```
(In main program)
procedure TForm1.btnShowFormClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  v_F : TfrmForm01;
begin
  v_F := TfrmForm01.Create(self);
  v_F.Init(True);
end;

procedure TForm1.btnShowModalFormClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  v_F : TfrmForm01;
begin
  v_F := TfrmForm01.Create(self);
  v_F.Init(False);
end;
```

I wrote and tested this example in Delphi7.